# Angular 2 how to emit method in component child to component parent

Tags: angular

I tried to erase an input field from the child component, it is transferred by `@Output` information that would activate a method `delete()` in the parent component!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can acomplish that using `EventEmitter` and `@Output`:

In following snippet, you can call `passDataToParent()` function to pass the desired data.

**child.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
       selector: 'app-child-component',
       templateUrl: './child.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
    })

    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
        // ******** Important part ****** 
        @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter();
        dataToEmit : any = "data to pass to parent component"; 

          constructor() {}

          ngOnInit() { }

          //Call this function to pass data
          passDataToParent() {
             this.emitter.emit(this.dataToEmit);
          }
    }
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChildComponent } from './child-component';

    @Component({
       selector: 'app-parent-component',
       templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
    })

    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

        // ******** Get reference of child component ****** 
        @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) child : ChildComponent ;

          constructor() {}

          ngOnInit() { }

          receiveDataFromChild(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
    }
```

Finally in parent HTML

**parent.component.html**

```
    <app-child (emitter)="receiveDataFromChild($event)"></app-child >
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thk you!! but I have already started reading the book! ^^ thck for you help

Answer (score 0):

Use eventEmitter. Here I deleted value of selected items, but you can remove item. For async render problem u can use output EventEmitter with true.

[I made example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HWlK8p6RnvcM485lcAto?p=preview)

```
  @Input() items: any[];
  @Input() selectedItem: any;
  keys: string[] = [];

  @Input() sorting: string;

  @Output() selectedItemChange = new EventEmitter<any>(true);
```