# Two-way binding a boolean for modal in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to maintain the state of a modal using a two-way bound variable in my host component. Thus, `<my-modal [(isOpen)]="isModalOpen"></my-modal>` should work.

For this, I added an event emitter inside my modal component: `@Output() isOpenEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false)`. Another attribute is the boolean itself `@Input() isOpen: boolean = false;`. A function `close()` exists that does the following: `this.isOpen = false; this.isOpenEvent.emit(false)`. A button in the HTML calls this `close()` function.

The host component has its own local variable that is expected to update when the modal's `close()` function is called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `isOpenEvent` with `isOpenChange`

Comment: Hi, I would like to read more about this. Could you link me to the documentation please?

Comment: The documentation doesn't clearly state this :-) it gives an example with `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` by combining the two you get `[(ngModel)]` two-way binding. I can provide it as an answer if the issue is solved.

Comment: It is solved. Wish it was stated explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `isOpenEvent` should be `isOpenChange` in order for two-way binding to work.

the brackets `[]` means property binding whereas paranthesis `()` are event binding as you know. The event binding should end with a `Change` in order for the same-name two-way binding to work.

I know the documentation "hides" this valuable info but check the lines

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the `SizerComponent` binding into this:

in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

---

**tl;dr**

`[isOpen]` + `(isOpenChange)` = `[(isOpen)]`

Answer (score 1):

I dont see in your snippet the function that is being called in the parent component when you emmit your event from modal component.

In the parent HTML you should have something like that:

```
  <app-modal (emitter)="receiveDataFromChild($event)"></app-modal>
```

and in the parent .ts file this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './modal-component';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-parent-component',
   templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    private isOpen = false;
    // ******** Get reference of child component ****** 
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) child : ChildComponent ;

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() { }

      receiveDataFromChild(data) {
          this.isOpen = data;
      }
}
```

Take a look at :[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308310/2860519)

Hope this helps!